# calculate MPEG frame length (ms)

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, mpeg-2

I'm looking all over the Internet for information in regards to calculating the frame length and it's been hard... I was able to successfully calculate the frame length in ms of MPEG-4, AAC, using:

```
frameLengthMs = mSamplingRate/1000
```

This works since there is one sample per frame on AAC.  For MPEG-1 or MPEG-2 I'm confused.  There are 1152 samples per frame, ok, so what do I do with that? :P

**Frame sample:**

```
MPEGDecoder(23069): mSamplesPerFrame: 1152
MPEGDecoder(23069): mBitrateIndex: 7
MPEGDecoder(23069): mFrameLength: 314
MPEGDecoder(23069): mSamplingRate: 44100
MPEGDecoder(23069): mMpegAudioVersion 3
MPEGDecoder(23069): mLayerDesc 1
MPEGDecoder(23069): mProtectionBit 1
MPEGDecoder(23069): mBitrateIndex 7
MPEGDecoder(23069): mSamplingRateFreqIndex 0
MPEGDecoder(23069): mPaddingBit 1
MPEGDecoder(23069): mPrivateBit 0
MPEGDecoder(23069): mChannelMode 1
MPEGDecoder(23069): mModeExtension 2
MPEGDecoder(23069): mCopyright 0
MPEGDecoder(23069): mOriginal 1
MPEGDecoder(23069): mEmphasis 0
MPEGDecoder(23069): mBitrate: 96kbps
```

Comment: Don't know about mpeg4/aac, but an MP3 audio frame is 0.028 seconds. Possibly that's carried over to mpeg4.

Comment: MPEG4 no need for that :)  So about MP3 the frame is always 28ms? Even MPEG1 MPEG2 and MPEG2.5?

Comment: That's true for audio frames. I've never looked into the video portions of MPEG, so can't say anything about those.

Comment: Thanks for your help... If you don't mind please post your answer and I'll set it as the answer for this post :)

Comment: It's not really an answer, though. So no biggie.

Comment: Marc, for some reason 0.028 sec seems a little too long on my tests. Which consists counting the total frames mult by 28ms.  That doesn't seem to match the players decoder... well this might be another issue...

Comment: Ok, so I believe 0.028 is not the frame length... I think it's 0.026.  Could you confirm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The duration of an MPEG audio frame is a function of the sampling rate and the number of samples per frame. The formula is:

```
frameTimeMs = (1000/SamplingRate) * SamplesPerFrame
```

In your case this would be

```
frameTimeMs = (1000/44100) * 1152
```

Which yields ~26ms per frame. For a different sampling rate you would get a different duration. The key is MPEG audio always represents a fixed number of samples per frame, but the time duration of each sample is dependent on the sampling rate.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your answer! Even dough this makes sense, how did you figure out this particular formula?

Comment: Well, the sampling rate is the number of samples per second. Period is the reciprocal of frequency (T = 1/f), so each sample has an period of 1/44100 seconds. Once you know the duration of a sample, you just multiply by the number of samples in a frame.

Comment: What about the channels carried by one frame? Ie, if we are using 2 channels (stereo), shouldn't it be frameTimeMMs = (1000/44100)*(1152*2)? The more channels are in the frame, the longer it takes, right?

Comment: No, because each channel occurs simultaneously. To be strictly accurate I could have said `SamplesPerChannelPerFrame` above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 1024, not 1000. See https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/94a316b05a95187cfacccc5d3d9483c06fbff809/isoparser/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/authoring/tracks/AACTrackImpl.java#L144

Comment: @basin The linked code is calculating the number of AAC packets per second, based on on AAC having 1024 samples per packet (frame). The 1000 above is the number of milliseconds in a second.