# How calculate MPEG-1, 2 frame duration

Tags: rtp, mpeg

I am trying to make a .mp4 file from the audio and video rtp packets of an IP camera.

When the audio format in the camera is configured as MPEG-2 ADTS i receive rtp packets with a payload size of 144 bytes, but these are made of two audio frames 72 bytes each.

However, when i configure the format as MPEG-1 the payload is made of only one audio frame.

What is the reason for this difference? I could get this info from some bits of the payload? as i do for the bitrate, samplerate, etc. I have read that the theoric packet size is 144 bytes, so how could i retrieve the frame size and number of frames in the package?

Besides, in order to calculate the theoric frame duration i am using the next formula:

time = 1/bitrate * framesize (in bytes) * 8

This is working well in the case of MPEG-2 with different combinations of bitrate and samplerate. However, it does not seem to work for the MPEG-1. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at: https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=61430.0  AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294807/calculate-mpeg-frame-length-ms